# numba did not speed up the compilation of code

Tags: python, performance, gpu, numba, jit

I tried this code with numba as well as normal mode but both were completed in 13 seconds and numba did not add speed

How can I set numba for this situation?

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, cuda
a=[]
@jit(target_backend="cuda")
def func():
    for i in range(100000):
        a.append(i)
    return a

print(func())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CUDA cannot be used here** because this code cannot run on the GPU (and even if would be modified, it would be inefficient). GPUs are very different from CPUs and they are also programmed differently. To understand why, please **read the [CUDA programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html)**

If you just run the code and **read the warnings** from Numba, then you can see that the code **fallback to a basic Python implementation**:

> Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "func" failed type inference due to: Untyped global name 'a': Cannot type empty list

The reason is that the type of `a` is not provided and Numba fail to find it. Numba is fast because of its typing system which enable it to compile the code in a native binary.

Additionally, you should not modify global variables. This is not a good idea in term of software engineering and Numba does not support that anyway.

Thus, you need to use a **typed lists** returned from the function. Not that typed lists are not much faster than Python list when read/written from/to CPython because Numba has to make the **conversion from/to CPython lists** which is an expensive operation. Still, on my machine this is about 3 times faster.

Corrected code:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, cuda

@jit
def func():
    a=[]
    for i in range(100000):
        a.append(i)
    return a

func() # Compile the function during the first run

a = func() # Execute quickly the code

print(a) # Printing is slow
```

For more information about the lazy compilation **please read the [Numba documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jit.html)**.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help

I searched the internet and in one of the comments I found that numba and also the compilation system do not have a good relationship with append and print commands and even numpy commands because they need more time to compile but I changed the code and this I changed the shape, an example of which can also be seen in this link, but I was not very familiar with it and I did not know why it really worked in this way.

Comment: Link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/running-python-script-on-gpu/

Comment: Maybe you have these two questions, why do we make a list of one?
And why do we use numpy?

Since append is slower and the length of our list is also known, so we come to create a list with a certain length of 1s (using numpy) and then when we have in the for loop we read those list values ​​instead of append We use alternatives or similar cases

This way, numba is not a problem either. In addition, Python's default array takes much longer than numpy, so we can have faster speeds in several ways.

Comment: For friends who are new to numba:

Try to use commands that are not like append or sort and such because they all make you spend more time

You can use numba and numpy anywhere, as long as you give numba items to calculate that are simple, and especially if they are inside the loop, for example, if you use special commands in graphic software, you have an error at the same time. And the time is more than normal

Comment: Finally, I made the impossible possible in my plugin for blender software

Plugin time in calculations was reduced from a few minutes to 6 seconds with the whole loop

Not only on the gpu, but based on what I told you, the compilation speed of the cpu also became easier

Comment: Well, **this tutorial is completely wrong**. It does not run anything on the GPU. It just compare a CPython implementation with a native CPU one. I fact the `target="cuda"` keyword is deprecated (AFAIK since a long time) and does nothing here. Even if it would magically work, the benchmark is biased as it include the compilation time. Please read the [documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cuda/index.html) and do not trust such tutorial. All of this is available in it and relatively clear (though not very complete).

Comment: As for `sort`, yes it tends to be slower (like random functions too). Not all functions are faster in Numba. However, `append` should be faster. And yes using Numpy array is generally better than using lists. For the compilation, note that you can use an eager compilation or an AOT. See the documentation: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jit.html . You can also enable a compilation cache not to recompile the code every time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help
So in fact all this is done on the cpu right?

Comment: So if it does not use a graphics card, we practically do not need to install the CUDA Toolkit

Comment: Yes, this is a CPU code and yes you do not need CUDA to be installed nor an Nvidia GPU ;) .